# jQuery remove a td that contains img src blank

Tags: jquery

```
<td>
    <img width="8" height="1" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="">
    </td>
```

how can i remove a td that contains `<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match a `<img />` which is a child of a `td` using a combination of the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('td > img[src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"]')
```

and then select it's parent using [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent), and remove it using [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove);

```
$('img[src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"]').parent().remove();
```

Comment: Hmm what if he has more '<img width="8" height="1" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="">' around there that are not childs of <td>'s? they will be removed as well.

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: Yep, but he can easily restrict that.. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('td > img[src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"]').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to put the ancestor directly before the img :

```
$('td img[src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"]').parent().remove();
```

According to  http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img[src$='blank.gif']").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add style.

img[src*="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"] {
    display: none;
}

This is worked for me